# Javascript not loading when I click on link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some scripts in my sales.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('.datepicker').datepicker()
  return

$('.flexdatalist').flexdatalist minLength: 1


$(document).ready ->
  $('.phoneMask').inputmask '(99) 9999[9]-9999'
  $('.cpfMask').inputmask '999.999.999-99'
  $('.cnpjMask').inputmask '99.999.999/9999-99'
  $('.dateMask').inputmask '99/99/9999'
  return


$ ->
  $('.valorMask').maskMoney()
  return
```

But this javascripts only load if i refresh page.

How can solve this?

Comment: Are you saying the JS only runs on the initial page load and not if you navigate to other pages? And are you using Turbolinks?

Comment: The JS only run if i refresh page. Yes, i'm using turbolink

Comment: Seems like a turbolinks issue Try `$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ready` instead `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 0):

When you use Turbolinks, `$(document).ready` only runs on the initial page load.

Try using the `page:load` listener instead of `ready`.

```
$(document).on 'page:load', ->
```